# How to Pass NSArray Parameter to Completion Block

Tags: ios, ios4

I want to pass the another NSArray as parameter , to completion block method ,as i am new to this concept, i can not understand the how to do it.Currently i am passing only one array, but now  i want to pass second nsarray , in second array i want to pass with array with value so that i can use over there

```
typedef void(^completion)(NSArray *list);
 -(void) getMoreData:(completion) completion
```

**Calling Method**

```
[Magento.service getMoreData:^(NSArray *list ) {
        if(list){
                 }
```

in above method i want to Pass NSArray , this method is in different class and i am calling from different . this array is using in this method .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it just as a C function, for example, I have declared a new class `MyClass`. The content of the interface file is:

```
typedef void(^completion)(NSArray *list);

@interface MyClass : NSObject

- (void)getMoreData:(completion)completionBlock;

@end
```

and in the implementation

```
- (void)getMoreData:(completion)completionBlock
{
    // fullfil your array
    NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, @3];

    // call the completion block
    completionBlock(array);
}
```

and I am using it as follow:

```
MyClass *myClassInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClassInstance getMoreData:^(NSArray *list) {
    if (list) {
        NSLog(@"%@", list);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Nil array");
    }
}];
```

and the output is:

```
2013-05-09 16:29:00.676 Test[823:11303] (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
```

Comment: what i need is i want to pass second NSArray means two array at the same time, and second with filled data

Comment: do you want to send an array to the method `getMoreData` or you want that your black return two different arrays?

Comment: no i want to send two array one with value and second with no value but when it return i wan only one array.

Comment: if you want to return an array from your block you don't need to add a second parameter, just change the return type from void to NSArray in the typedef

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29711/discussion-between-bhupendrasinh-and-tkanzakic)

Answer (score 0):

It is not your responsibility to pass an array to the completion block. In the situation you're describing, it is the getMoreData that invokes the completion block so it is that method that passes an array to the block.

```
- (void) getMoreData: (completion) completion
{
    ...some code...
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    if(completion)
        completion(array);

    ...some code...
}
```

Your responsibility is just to pass a completion block that is going to make use of the array created in the getMoreData method.